# How can I recognize a tap onto the back of a phone when it is in a pocket on the lockscreen?

Tags: ios

I want to be able to recognize a double tap on the phone when it is in the users pocket. I know sleep cycle has a feature like this for snooze. Is this possible to implement while the phone is locked? Can apps still receive accelerometer data when locked? I don't know how else one would code this besides using the accelerometer.